# Why cant i get my contact form to send the message?

Tags: html, forms, contacts

I cant seem to get my contact form working. Here is my contact form code:

```
<form action="MAILTO: Dana@dogmother.ca" method="post" >
                <div class="to">
                    <input type="text" class="text" value="Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}"style="margin-left: 10px">
                    <input type="text" class="text" value="Email" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}" style="margin-left: 10px">
                </div>
                <div class="to">
                    <input type="text" class="numbers" value="Phone Number" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Phone Number';}"style="margin-left: 10px">
                    <input type="text" class="text" value="Subject" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Subject';}" style="margin-left: 10px">
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                   <textarea value="Message:" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Message';}">Message:</textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="submit">Submit</a>
                </div>
           </form>
```

I have tried changing the `mailto` to my address and it still hasn't sent then I saw the submit button with a herf link but I don't know if I need to use or how to use that to make it work.

Comment: the action attribute in the form cannot send directly to an email.  It typically is looking for a script (ASP, PHP, etc.) to process the form data and send it that way.

Comment: @ja408 - Yes, it can.

Comment: so how do i do it? @j08691

Comment: sorry you are right, jo8691, but it's not advisable.  try removing the space after the colon.  mailto:drana...

Comment: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/279460

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the things you are missing:
 - Submit button should be an input type submit or a button.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
```

Anchors that are not told to action the form won't do a thing.

- None of your input's have names. Forms submit in name/value pairs. If you don't name your value it won't work, for example:

```html
<input name='Name' type="text" class="text" value="Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}"style="margin-left: 10px">
```

See [this tutorial](http://webdesign.about.com/od/forms/ss/how-to-create-a-simple-mailto-form.htm) to see what else you might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button doesn't do anything. Try:

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a submit button, not a link, and names for your inputs:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qg788yfr/)**

```
<form action="MAILTO: Dana@dogmother.ca" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  <div class="to">
    <input type="text" class="text" name="name" value="Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}" style="margin-left: 10px">
    <input type="text" class="text" name="email" value="Email" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}" style="margin-left: 10px">
  </div>
  <div class="to">
    <input type="text" class="numbers" name="phone" value="Phone Number" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Phone Number';}" style="margin-left: 10px">
    <input type="text" class="text" name="subject" value="Subject" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Subject';}" style="margin-left: 10px">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <textarea value="Message:" name="message" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Message';}">Message:</textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </div>
</form>
```

By on a side note, this is highly unadvisable. You should use a real mailing script and not rely on the client to actually create and send the email.

Answer (score -1):

you should do it like this:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <!-- form stuff like inputs, etc. -->
</form>
```

and in your `process.php` file use `mail()` function ike this:

```
mail("Dana@dogmother.ca","My subject","This is the message");
```

Comment: its html not php i stated that in the tags

Answer (score -1):

`<form>` works only with http protocol by its definition.

To send email using default email application you can use ordinary `<a>` element and compose its href attribute.

Try this:

```html
<a href="mailto:example@example.com?subject=hello&body=world">Email Me!</a>
```